# Probability Estimator

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, machine-learning

Hi I was going through the MIT 2005 Machine Learning homework assignments and I was having trouble understanding a few concepts in probability theory. I would be obliged if anyone could validate my answers, or if I am wrong, point me in the right direction.

Here is a link to the original problem set: http://www.slideshare.net/adimanunited/ps1-v3-r

We have a set of unidimensional data, $X1, . . . , Xn$, drawn from the positive reals. We will consider two diﬀerent models for its distribution:

**• Model 1**: The data are drawn from a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, b]$. This model
has a single positive real parameter, $0 < b$.

**• Model 2**: The data are drawn from a uniform distribution on the interval $[a, b]$. This model
has two positive real parameters, $a$ and $b$, such that $0 < a < b$.

**Question 0**: What’s the mean of each of the distributions?

My answer: $b/2$ for the first one, $(a+b)/2$ for the second one.

In model 1, we just need to consider the distribution of $f_{\hat b}$. Generally speaking, the pdf of the maximum of a set of data drawn from pdf $f$, with cdf $F$, is
$f_{\hat b} (x) = nF(x)^{n−1}f(x) $.

The idea is that, if $x$ is the maximum, then $n − 1$ of the other data values will have to be less than $x$, and the probability of that is $F(x)^{n−1}$, and then one value will have to equal $x$, the probability
of which is $f(x)$. We multiply by $n$ because there are $n$ different ways to choose the data value that could be the maximum.

**Question 1**: What is $f_{\hat b}$ in the particular case where the data are drawn uniformly from $0$ to $b$?

My answer: $f_{\hat b}=1/b$

**Question 2**: Write an expression for the expected value of $\hat \mu$, as an integral.

My answer: $$
\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} x{f_{\hat b}(x)} ~ \mathrm{d}{x}.
$$

**Question 3**: What is the squared bias of $\hat \mu$? Is this estimator unbiased? Is it asymptotically unbiased?

I know  $bias^2(\hat \theta) = (ED[\hat \theta] − \theta)^2$ but not able to move ahead.

**Question 4**:Write an expression for the variance of $\hat \mu$, as an integral.

I know I can get the answer as $$
\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} (x-\mu)^2{f_{\hat b}(x)} ~ \mathrm{d}{x}.
$$
but the actual result should be $V [\hat \mu]=b^2 n/(4 (n+1)^2 (n+2))$ and I get a totally different value.

**Question 5**: What is the mean squared error of $\hat \mu$?

I know that $MSE=bias^2+var$ but I am not able to get any of those.

Kindly help.

Comment: What does f^b mean?

Comment: The sheer quantity of questions you have is too much to address in a single post, taking into consideration your current level of understanding.  Asking for help on all five questions when you need to be able to just get the first part correct is a bit too ambitious for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for the first part only.  Our estimate of the parameter $b$ is $$\hat b = \max_i X_i,$$ the largest observation in our sample.  We are told that the density of $\hat b$ is given by $$f_{\hat b}(x) = nF_X(x)^{n-1} f_X(x),$$ where $F_X$ and $f_X$ are the CDF and density of each of the $X_i$s; i.e., it is the CDF and PDF of a (continuous) uniform distribution.  If this distribution is uniform on $[0,b]$, then clearly $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{b}, \quad F_X(x) = \frac{x}{b}, \quad 0 < x < b.$$  Therefore, the PDF of $\hat b$ is $$f_{\hat b}(x) = n \biggl( \frac{x}{b} \biggr)^{n-1} \frac{1}{b} = \frac{nx^{n-1}}{b^n}.$$

Try to think carefully about how the other questions can be answered in light of the above.

Comment: so the expected value of $E[{\hat \mu}]$ should be $n*b/2*(n+1)$ but I am getting $n*b/(n+1)$. using integration.

Comment: Can you point me to some source that will help me in understanding these concepts?